# What am I doing wrong with this program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write a code to convert a letter grade to a numerical value. I have this code but when I run it, I get an error saying `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab6Smalls {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String grade;
    String letter1;
    String letter2;
    double gpa = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");

    grade = scan.nextLine();
    letter1 = grade.substring(0,1);
    letter2 = grade.substring(1,2);

    if (letter1.equals("A") && letter2.equals("+")){
        gpa = 4.3;
    } else if (letter1.equals("A")){
        gpa = 4.0;
    } else if (letter1.equals("B")){
        gpa = 3.0;
    } else if (letter1.equals("C")){
        gpa = 2.0;
    } else if (letter1.equals("D")){
        gpa = 1.0;
    } else if (letter1.equals("F")){
        gpa = 0.0;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The value is invalid.");
    }

    if (!letter1.equals("F")){
        if(letter2.equals("+") && !letter1.equals("A")) gpa += 0.3;
        else if(letter2.equals("-")) gpa -= 0.3;
    }

    System.out.println("The numerical value is " + gpa + ".");
  }
}
```

Comment: Great opportunity for you to attach a debugger with your IDE of choice and walk through the code line by line. Somebody pointing out the problem to you would rob you of the chance to learn that. Another great alternative is read up on what a Java stacktrace (error) is and how to read one. Both will get your issue resolved very quickly.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger to identify the line that's causing that runtime exception?

Comment: It was line 16, the only response I get back is A+. Every thing else brings up an error.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error because alphabets other than A+ do not have a second value

A+ has two letters

B has one so when you try to find a second, it breaks

C has one so when you try to find a second, it breaks

D has one so when you try to find a second, it breaks

You want to check if the second value exists, before you retrieve it.
Try this

```
String letter2 = "";
grade = scan.nextLine();
letter1 = grade.substring(0,1);

// Check, if there is a second letter, get it.
if (grade.length() >= 2) {
  letter2 = grade.substring(1,2);
}
```